# Configurable Product Sizes with Image Color

Tags: configurable-product

I have configurable product type that has color and size in my store. 
I make one configurable product and 6 simple products.
URL:
http://imageplus.pk/men-9/tees/men-s-reebok-kix-ready-or-not-regular-fit-tee.html

In this URL Color "Charcoal" with size 'S' and 'XXL' show charcoal color shirt image but on the 'L' size it show Red Color Shirt image. I want on the 'L' size its also show charcoal color shirt image.

Please let me know how can i do this?

thanks 
MUNEEB

Answer (score 1):

Remove text "red" from Label column on the Red Color Shirt Image in confgurable product.